# My filter is returning the whole object and not just the property

Tags: javascript, filter

I want to return an array of ids, but the whole object is being returned.
Do I have the correct syntax?

```js
const docIds = this.claim.claimDocuments.filter(doc => {
  if (doc.status !== 'Submitted') {
    return doc.id;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`filter` doesn't change the array, it just selects the entries which pass the logical test. You then need to `map` the output of `filter` to return only the `id` values:

```
const docIds = this.claim.claimDocuments
   .filter(doc => doc.status !== 'Submitted')
   .map(doc => doc.id);
```

Comment: You should also look at the other answer which has some methods which will likely have better performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an array from a portion of items in another while also transforming each passing item into something else, you'll have to use a different method, perhaps by initializing the array, then pushing inside the `if` while iterating:

```
const docIds = [];
for (const doc of this.claim.claimDocuments) {
  if (doc.status !== 'Submitted') {
    docIds.push(doc.id);
  }
}
```

Or with `.reduce`:

```
const docIds = this.claim.claimDocuments.reduce((a, doc) => {
  if (doc.status !== 'Submitted') {
    a.push(doc.id);
  }
  return a;
}, []);
```

Or with `.filter` followed by `.map`, though this requires iterating over some items twice.